# Wrap text in div with ellipses (+ drop wrapping of floating div)

Tags: css, html

Ok been banging my head against the desk for awhile with this one .. want to achieve the following

1) Header (nav) should be on one line with no wrapping (this includes nav-back, nav-title & nav-next)

2) when you shrink the window nav-title should shrink AND when the window doesn't allow the ability to show all the text it should be cut off with ellipses (eg 'This is way too lon..')

Here is what I'm working from:

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-back"><</div>
<div class="nav-title">
    <div class="nav-main-title">Want this no-wrap with ellipses</div>
    <div id="default-page-sub-title" class="nav-sub-title">Same here</div>
</div>
<div class="nav-next">></div>
```

with [styling on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYYTy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying the ellipses overflow properties to the `.nav` container instead of the titles.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYYTy/43/)

**CSS**

```
.nav .nav-main-title, .nav .nav-sub-title {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width: inherit;
}
```